# .htaccess Redirect all pages except one and another internal redirect of a certain domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all request of one particular domain to another, except for one page request. I hope my attempt explains what I try to do:

```
RewriteEngine on

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^host\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^link/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$          dokument_by_link.php?$1=1&document_type=$2&value=$3 [NC,L]

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^host\.mysite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/link/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^dokument_by_link\.php
RewriteRule (.*)                                    https://www.anothersite.de/$1 [R=302,L]

#This should not apply to host.mysite.com, but I think this is already accomplished by the L-flag above
RewriteRule ^test/?$                                       test.php [L,NC]
```

host.mysite.com/link/ should be redirected to host.mysite.com/document_by_link.php

`RewriteRule ^link/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$           dokument_by_link.php?$1=1&document_type=$2&value=$3 [NC,L]`

All other requests should be redirected to `https://www.anothersite.de`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is  unclear. What do you mean by " . But the request also needs a redirect." ? and    What URL  you want to exclude from the redirection?

Comment: @AmitVerma Thanks for your comment. Is it now clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
RewriteEngine on

#rewrite /link to /document_by_link.php
RewriteRule ^link/?$ /document_by_link.php [L]
#redirect all other URLs to https://www.anothersite.de
RewriteRule !dokument_by_link\.php$ https://www.anothersite.de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it does not work. The first rule works fine by itself. But as soon as I add the second rule the first one does not work anymore:

`RewriteRule ^link/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$   dokument_by_link.php?$1=1&document_type=$2&value=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule .+https://www.onwalt.de/$1 [L,R=302]`

Comment: @Phantom Do you get any error? How does it not work?

Comment: `https://host.mysite.com` is not redirected to `https://www.anothersite.de`. After changing `.+` to `(.*)` the redirect works. But the link to document_by_link redirect does not work.

Comment: `https://host.mysite.com/link/first/second/third` is also redirected to `https://www.anothersite.de`

Comment: @Phantom I have updated the rule. Please reload the page to see it.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works great! Can we also limit those rules to the host `host.mysite.com`?

Comment: @Phantom Yes ofcourse we can ! You just need to put a host condition above the rule you want to limit to that host. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host\.mysite\.com$ [NC]` .

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/link/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.anothersite.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^link/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ dokument_by_link.php?$1=1&document_type=$2&value=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^test/?$ test.php [L,NC]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` here as `REQUEST_URI` may change to a rewritten URI whereas `THE_REQUEST` remains same for the scope of a web request.

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Thank you very much, but this does not work. The first redirect (all pages to anothersite) does not apply

Comment: Thank you! You updated rules seem to work. Can I also limit the first rule to the host `host.mysite.com`? What is the difference between `!^/link/` and `!\s/link/`? Why do you use `^` instead of `(.*)`?

Comment: Yes we can limit, see my updated answer and also see not on `THE_REQUEST`. Here `THE_REQUEST` starts with `GET` or `POST` or `PUT` etc followed by a single space. Where as `REQUEST_URI` stats with actual URI

Comment: Thank you very much! That works great. To be fair: I will accept the answer to @Amit Verma, because his approach does also work and he answered first.

Comment: Thank you also very much! See you around!